# Virtual Private Server Hosting Price

Tags: ffmpeg, resources, video-streaming, web-hosting, vps

Can you tell me a VPS that has an unlimited bandwidt a low price but very powerful for streaming website?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you ask doesn't [to my knowledge] exist [super cheap, high bandwidth, free VPS].  Unless it is "hosting it from your home internet connection" that might be unlimited, though typically doesn't have enough upload bandwidth to be great, no high availability, etc.  There are VPS's that give you "quite a bit" of bandwdith: ramnode, linode, digitalocean, vultr come to mind.  And all seem to have high quality cpu's. GL!